# Is it possible to convert %who DataFrame to a list in IPython Notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I know that the magic command `%who DataFrame` can print out a list of dataframes in the workspace. I wonder if it's possible to make the output into a list for referencing back later?

For example,

```
import pandas as pd
df_1 = pd.DataFrame()
df_2 = pd.DataFrame()
%who DataFrame
```

returns:

```
df_1     df_2
```

I tried things like `list(%who DataFrame)` and `output = %who DataFrame` and none has worked.

Comment: Why do you want this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`who` only prints the results, it doesn't return anything you can access (you'd need to intercept the stream).  But you can us [`who_ls`](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/interactive/magics.html#magic-who_ls) instead, which is what `who` calls:

```
In [23]: df0 = pd.DataFrame()

In [24]: df1 = pd.DataFrame()

In [25]: w = %who DataFrame
df0  df1     

In [26]: w

In [27]: w = %who_ls DataFrame

In [28]: w
Out[28]: ['df0', 'df1']

In [29]: type(w)
Out[29]: list
```

Comment: Hi @DSM, I have a follow-up question. I thought by doing so, it will let me reference back to the dataframes and describe all the dataframe at one shot  `for df in w: print df.describe()`. But the df is literally treated as unicode.  `unicode' object has no attribute 'describe'` Is there anyway to work around this? Thanks very much!

Comment: @Lily: `who_ls` returns the *names* of the dataframes, not the dataframes themselves.  If you want to turn the name into the object, you could do something like `dfs = [eval(name) for name in w]` or `[locals()[name] for name in w]` or something, but usually when you're doing this for anything other than debugging purposes it's a bad idea.

Comment: I see. Thank you a lot for the heads-up. Really helpful!